# Removing list of words from a text file in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two files.

1. File 1. Has a list of all the dictionary words
2. File 2. Has a list of
   all prepositions.

I want to remove all the prepositions from the dictionary.
I want to reduce the number of lines in my code and also make it more elegant, idiomatic and readable.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby

    path = "/Users/../Desktop/";

    file_original_wordlist = File.open("#{path}"  + "dictionary.txt",  "r")
    file_remove_wordlist = File.open("#{path}"  + "prepositions.txt", "r")

    # Need to initialize the variables else I get errors
    delete_word = false
    word_orig =  ''
    word_rem  =  ''
    count = 0
    file_original_wordlist.each_line do |line1|
      file_remove_wordlist.each_line do |line2|
        word_orig =  line1
        word_rem  =  line2 
        if word_orig.eql?(word_rem)
          puts "Deleting the word " + word_rem
          delete_word = true 
          count++
        end   
      end
      if delete_word == false
        File.open(path + "scrubbed_list.txt", "a") {|f| f.write(word_orig) }
      end
  # Need to reopen the file otherwise after the first iteration to start from the beginning 
      file_remove_wordlist = File.open("#{path}"  + "prepositions.txt", "r")
      delete_word = false
    end

    puts "Deleted " + count + " words in total"
```

Comment: I ran some benchmarks that I reported in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some notes:

- I guess you come from imperative languages. Try to write in a more functional style (more expressions, less statements).
- Use libraries (`File`) to manipulate paths.
- This double `each_line` is bad news for performance: O(n*m). Avoid it by building a data structure that has O(1) checks for inclusion. I'd create a `set` of the prepositions (it's the smaller set). The overall performance is now O(n).

I'd write:

```
prepositions = open(File.join(path, "prepositions.txt")).lines.to_a 
words = open(File.join(path, "dictionary.txt")).lines.to_a
filtered_words = words - prepositions
File.write("dictionary_without_prepositions.txt", filtered_words.join)
```

If the input file `dictionary.txt` is very, very large, this is a more lazy aproach:

```
require 'set'
prepositions = open(File.join(path, "prepositions.txt")).lines.to_set

open("dictionary_without_prepositions.txt", "w") do |output| 
  open(File.join(path, "dictionary.txt")).lines.each do |line|
    unless prepositions.include?(line)
      output.write(line)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: +1 for the use of `to_set` for the prepositions - you should expand on why you chose it.

Comment: @UriAgassi. Done!

Comment: Great @tokland. Performance is actually O(n+m), though - you need to build the set...

Comment: @UriAgassi: it's my understanding that O(n+m), m<=n -> O(n) (at worst what would be "O(2n)", but constants are ignored, so O(n)).

Comment: if you know that m<=n, you are right. More generally, though `O(n+m)==O(max(n,m))`. If you have a big preposition file, and a small dictionary, the preposition file will be the dominant factor in your complexity.

Comment: From what OP said, I think it's safe to assume `n >> m`: "File 1. Has a list of all the dictionary words. File 2. Has a list of all prepositions".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in Ruby with very little code.  Here's one way:

```
DICT_FNAME     = "#{path}"  + "dictionary.txt"
NEW_DICT_FNAME = "#{path}"  + "new_dictionary.txt"
PREP_FNAME     = "#{path}"  + "prepositions.txt"

all_words    = File.read(DICT_FNAME).split($/).map(&:strip)
prepositions = File.read(PREP_FNAME).split($/).map(&:strip)
File.write(NEW_DICT_FNAME, (all_words - prepositions).join($/))

puts "#{all_words.size} words in the dictionary"
puts "#{prepositions.size} prepositions to be removed"
```

Let's try it out.  First, write some words to the dictionary file and to the file containing the prepositions:

```
all = <<_
Now
is
the
time
for
all
Rubyists
to
debug
_

preps = <<_
for
to
_

all   #=> "Now\nis\nthe\ntime\nfor\nall\nRubyists\nto\ndebug\n"
preps #=> "for\nto\n"

path = ''

DICT_FNAME = "#{path}"  + "dictionary.txt"   #=> "dictionary.txt"
PREP_FNAME = "#{path}"  + "prepositions.txt" #=> "prepositions.txt"

File.write(DICT_FNAME, all)   #=> 42
File.write(PREP_FNAME, preps) #=>  7
```

Now we read the two input files [`$/` is the end-of-line character(s)]:

```
NEW_DICT_FNAME = "#{path}" + "new_dictionary.txt"

all_words    = File.read(DICT_FNAME).split($/).map(&:strip)
  #=> ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "for", "all", "Rubyists", "to", "debug"]    
prepositions = File.read(PREP_FNAME).split($/).map(&:strip)
  #=> ["for", "to"]

puts "#{all_words.size} words in the dictionary"
  #=> 9 words in the dictionary
puts "#{prepositions.size} prepositions to be removed"
  #=> 2 prepositions to be removed
```

...then remove the elements of the `prepositions` array from the `all_words` array:

```
diff = all_words - prepositions
  #=> ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "all", "Rubyists", "debug"]
```

...format it for writing:

```
joined = diff.join($/)
  #=> "Now\nis\nthe\ntime\nall\nRubyists\ndebug"
```

...write the output file:

```
File.write(NEW_DICT_FNAME, joined)
```

...and confirm it it was written correctly:

```
File.read(NEW_DICT_FNAME).split($/).map(&:strip)
  #=> ["Now", "is", "the", "time", "all", "Rubyists", "debug"]
```

Edit: In view of @Tokland's suggestion of constructing a set of prepositions when processing the words one at a time, I thought it might be interesting to run some benchmarks.  You'll see that I just used random arrays and words, rather than read and write to files.

```
L = Array('a'..'z')

require 'set'

def make_samples(n,m,k,s)
  s.times.with_object([]) do |_,a|
    # Construct a sample of n unique words, each of length k
    all_words = make_sample(n,k)
    # Assume the first m words are prepositions
    preps     = all_words[0,m]
    # Shuffle the words (no need to further randomize the prepositions) 
    a << [all_words.shuffle, preps]
  end
end   

def make_sample(n,k)
  set_words = Set.new
  while set_words.size < n do
    set_words << k.times.with_object('') { |_,w| w << L.sample }
  end
  set_words.to_a
end
```

Here is an example of test data with 8 4-character words, of which 3 are prepositions, and a sample size of 2.

```
make_samples(8,3,4,2)
  #=> [[["fexz", "gxrv", "acte", "namz", "cpqw", "txsm", "zonm", "tvjz"],
  #     ["zonm", "gxrv", "fexz"]],
  #    [["nfdf", "djnv", "inqk", "tbgc", "asfb", "nqbg", "dnyb", "ywtv"],
  #     ["djnv", "tbgc", "inqk"]]]
```

These are the parameters I used for the results I report below:

```
n = 200_000 # number of words, inckluding prepositions
m = 40      # number of prepositions
k = 8       # length of each string
s = 20      # sample size

samples = make_samples(n,m,k,s)

Benchmark.bm('reject - arr'.size) do |bm|
  # words array - preps array 
  bm.report 'arr - arr' do
    samples.each { |(wa,pa)| wa - pa }
  end

  # reject words in preps array
  bm.report 'reject - arr' do
    samples.each { |(wa,pa)| wa.reject { |w| pa.include? w } }
  end

  # reject words in preps set
  bm.report 'reject - set' do
    samples.each { |(wa,pa)| ps = pa.to_set; wa.reject { |w| ps.include? w } }
  end
end

                   user     system      total        real
arr - arr      0.860000   0.030000   0.890000 (  0.884945)
reject - arr  10.180000   0.020000  10.200000 ( 10.217233)
reject - set   1.830000   0.040000   1.870000 (  1.913069)
```

I ran a few additional tests with different parameters, but these results are indicative.

Comment: This would be my first choice if both files fit into memory.